# Choosing between several property sets in jdorn/json-editor

Tags: jsonschema

I have defined two different property sets in my JSON schema and I'm trying to put together an editor that will allow the user to choose one of several property sets and then fill the corresponding properties.

Here is my schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Test Configuration",
    "properties": {
        "master_property_set": {
            "title": "Testing oneOf",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "title": "Property set 1",
                    "properties": {
                        "property1": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "property2": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "title": "Property set 2",
                    "properties": {
                        "property3": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "property4": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, when I switch to `Property set 2`, my data still contains `property1` and `property2` as empty strings and they are displayed in the editor. They should get removed. What am I doing wrong?

The setup can be tested here: http://goo.gl/j91of7

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong.  It seems the editor is being conservative about removing properties from the form.  Technically, it's not invalid because your schema doesn't forbid additional properties, but I don't think this is intended behavior.  This is either a bug or it is done this way on purpose.  I can't think a reason this would need to be done on purpose so my money is on it being a bug.

Comment: I've found the answer and posted it. Looks like it's neither a bug, nor a feature, but an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer in the docs. Turns out `no_additional_properties` property of the editor needs to be set to true.

Answer (score -1):

```
    {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Test Configuration",
      "properties": {
        "master_property_set": {
          "title": "Testing oneOf",
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "type": "object",
              "title": "Property set 1",
              "properties": {
                "property1": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "property2": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "additionalProperties":false
            },
            {
              "type": "object",
              "title": "Property set 2",
              "properties": {
                "property3": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "property4": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "additionalProperties":false
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```